# Xcode SCM - Need help with checking files back in!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Okay, I have another newbie question.  I'm starting to work with a remote code repository, remotehosting.com, and have been given a username, password, and URL.  I've been able to successfully associate my project with a remote source code repository, have checked out/pulled down the source files, and have now made a small change to a single file.  Here's where my questions start.

1) I can't see anywhere in my GUI where Xcode realizes that I have made a change to a file
2) How do I check my files back in?

I gotta be missing something.  The docs I've been reading point to more menu items that I currently see under my SCM menu item.  Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your assistance!!!

Comment: Also, which SCM type - CVS, SVN, Git, ...?

Comment: Duh, I should've included that.  I'm running Xcode 3.2.3 against SVN.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Source Control -> Commit, Select the files that you want to commit, add a comment and hit commit button. 
This is the flow for xcode 4

Comment: Thanks.  I should've mentioned I was running 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3...

The Project window should have a column which displays the SCM status for your files. This can appear both in the "Groups & Files" outline view in the left pane and the file list in the right pane. The icon for the column is a little cylinder shape, a black-and-white version of the yellow cylinder that's shown when you manage repositories. If this column is not displayed, you can right-click on the header of either of those panes to bring up a menu with a list of columns. Select "SCM" from that. The status will display as the same one-letter codes that SVN uses on the command line.

In order to commit files, you can either a) select the particular files, or group you want to commit and use the menu command SCM>Commit Changes..., or b) Select SCM>Commit Entire Project... (which I personally have bound to ⌥-⌘-C in the Xcode key bindings preferences).

Either of these will display a sheet in which you can enter your commit message; the text field in this is very handy in that it accepts the Return key as a newline, rather than passing it to the "Commit" button, but could be confusing the first few times. Press ⌘-Return to activate the button and perform the commit.

Comment: The cylinder is a light black or gray but has an "X" over it.  When I hit Command-Return I got an error and upon investigation it tells me base SDK is missing in the top left of my Xcode GUI.  I can open other projects and I don't have this problem, but when I checked out/pulled down my current project from the repository I am somehow missing the base SDK.  Any ideas?

Comment: I hadn't initially, or so I thought.  Maybe I just didn't see I had a problem initially.  I need to do some research and will update the thread when I've got something solid.